# My Apache reverse proxy adds code to body of fetched HTML files from head tag

Tags: html, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a simple reverse proxy server using Apache 2.4.20 which gets HTML files from an internal Apache web server. The page fetching and URL rewriting is working fine, but there is a problem occurring.

After any webpage is passed through the proxy, three things are incorrect:  the contents of the head tag appears in the body, the head tag is missing and a mysterious ">" character in a "p" tag is added at the top of the body tag.

This extra `<p>></p>` code suggests to me something wrong with the detection of a HTML tag (it could be part of `<head>`). Also, even without content in the head tag, the body tag still begins with that weird code.

**Proxied content - viewed in developer tools, Google Chrome browser:**
[image: Screenshot image described on above line. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbxD8.png]

**Proxied content - original source of fetched file:**
[image: Screenshot image described on above line. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRs4R.png]

**Original HTML file - opened directly from internal server filesystem:**
[image: Screenshot image described on above line. https://i.stack.imgur.com/alxtr.png]

**Proxy server configuration file - section about transfer and `ProxyHTML`:**
[image: Screenshot image described on above line. https://i.stack.imgur.com/79t6b.png]

I know the original server is working correctly so this isn't causing the problem.
Here's a screenshot of the HTML file viewed directly from the original server in a browser (on the proxy server device), along with source code shown in Chrome Developer Tools:
[image: Screenshot image described in previous sentence. https://i.stack.imgur.com/y81UM.png]

*Update*: As expected, *mod_proxy_html* is the main cause of my problem (turning it off left the original file). However, this *isn't a solution* for me because I need the tool to rewrite relative URL references in the proxied documents. I read the [documentation page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) but it didn't describe any features that undoubtedly caused my problem.

List of *mod_proxy_html* directives from the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) which I think aren't relevant, some tested: *ProxyHTMLBufSize*, *ProxyHTMLCharsetOut*, *ProxyHTMLDocType*, *ProxyHTMLEnable*, *ProxyHTMLEvents*, *ProxyHTMLExtended* (default off), *ProxyHTMLFixups* (tried from suggestion), *ProxyHTMLInterp*, *ProxyHTMLLinks*, *ProxyHTMLMeta* (default off), *ProxyHTMLStripComments*, *ProxyHTMLURLMap*.

Comment: I've now made my post clearer and better formatted so it's hopefully more useful and easier to think about. I don't have access at the moment to the servers mentioned but the problem should be reproducible.

Comment: Yes, I confirm to have the same issue. It is something very weird, since I use the very same reverse proxy for other sites as well, and those work fine (<head> is not removed), and they have the same setup. I ran the html file through validator, it gives no warning, yet, the proxyhtml strips off the <head> and </head> for no good reason and no good outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. However, on the same machine, other sites that used the same reverse-proxy worked fine, even when they have exactly the same config, but different URL. I could not understand...  except after I have noticed that the files that had problem had the [BOM signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file!

This caused the ProxyHTML to be confused so much that it had removed the `<head>` and `</head>` tags.

After I have removed the BOM using the `dos2unix` utility, files were shown properly.

Your post gave me extra motivation for fighting this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are using mod_proxy_html

This mod will try to affect HTML resources proxied through depending on the directives. My advice would be to remove the ProxyHTML directives and see what comes back. If it is unaffected then you know its something to do with mod_proxy_html.

Then look at adding this directive below the ProxyHTMLEnable

```
ProxyHTMLFixups off
```

Comment: As I suspected, *mod_proxy_html* is causing my problem (turning it off solved the problem). This is not a solution for me though as I need it on to rewrite relative URL references in the proxied documents. Also, trying `ProxyHTMLFixups off` did not work (looking at its [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#ProxyHTMLFixups), I don't understand why it would have caused the error anyway). Looking at the whole [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html), I don't know what could have caused my problem.

Comment: I've now made my post clearer and better formatted so it's hopefully more useful and easier to think about. You could provide more ideas if you have any. I don't have access at the moment to the servers mentioned but the problem should be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the document type definition

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
```

the tag should not be closed. It should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

*mod_proxy_html* tries to fix what it sees as an extra `>` character by wrapping it in paragraph.